# How can I popup a message when users swipe right on the last page of UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipageviewcontroller

I am doing a book app, I want to popup a message saying "this is last page of the book." when users swipe to the next page on the last page of the book, because actually next page does not exist.

What event I should use?

Answer (score -1):

This message will be send to the `UIPageViewController` delegate:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Handle it here and show alert or whatever you want.